# How to have Entity Framework generate an additional model in a code first, existing database situation?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have created a context through the wizard, and set it to be code first, with an existing database.

A wizard poped up, just like in database first mode and asked which views/tables I wanted to add to my context.

Now I want the wizard to create a C# class from another table in that existing database.

Since there's no EDMX schema, there seems to be no way to get back to that menu to select additional views/tables.

I've read about enabling migration, but I'm a bit nervous about touching the database structure by running a migration by accident when in fact, all I want is EF to generate an additional class.

[This says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx) to run another "reverse engineer" to overwrite the class, but nothing is mentioned on how to do it.

How could I achieve that ?

EDIT: I switched to database first so I can reach that menu whenever I want, but I'd like an answer anyways.

Comment: Delete the classes generated the first time you ran the wizard and run the wizard again?

Comment: @Pawel That could work. Didn't think of it.

Comment: Maybe you don't even need to delete anything - just select the tables and I think wizard will overwrite the files.